# Eigen matmul runtime depending on order of multiplication

Tags: c++, eigen

I having problems where the runtime of a function involving some matrix multiplication changes depending on the order of the multiplication and the intermediate saved values. These are the variables...

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> C; \\ = a sparse matrix (NxM)
Eigen::MatrixXd M_inv; \\ = a dense matrix (NxN)
Eigen::VectorXd v; \\ = a dense vector (dim M)
```

and N << M. This is fast,

```
Eigen::VectorXd alpha = M_inv * C * v;
Eigen::VectorXd v_n = v - C.transpose() * alpha;
```

and these are very slow (don't finish),

```
Eigen::MatrixXd D = C.transpose() * M_inv * C;
Eigen::VectorXd v_n = v - D * v;
```

```
Eigen::VectorXd v_n = v - C.transpose() * M_inv * C * v;
```

Does this have to do with memory usage or something with sparse and dense matmul?

Edit: N is of order 10, M is of order 10^6

Comment: What is the size of each matrix/vector? Also what is the proportion of non-zero values in the sparse matrix (ie. sparsity) ?

Comment: That's the nature of a matrix multiplication by the way you can't just transpose them and get the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `(matrix * matrix) * vector` product will almost certainly evaluate slower than `matrix * (matrix * vector)`. Even in your fast version, you should make sure that you evaluate the product from right to left:

```
Eigen::VectorXd alpha = M_inv * (C * v);
Eigen::VectorXd v_n = v - C.transpose() * alpha;
```

And if you don't need `alpha` afterwards, you can also write this in one line:

```
Eigen::VectorXd v_n = v - C.transpose() * (M_inv * (C * v));
```

Comment: Good to know! I'll be sure to add parentheses and get rid of `alpha`. I actually end up reusing `D`. However, it seems like calculating `D` is very expensive and it's actually faster to avoid calculating it.